# how to keep a discord bot from randomly breaking

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot, it runs a set program when called. After there is any error in the program, if it is called again after that it will randomly keep values from the last usage or respond to itself breaking the code once again. here is the code.

```
from planetlists import planet_cap,planet_lvl,transfer,temp,credit_per_hour,planet_cost,max_levels_planet
import time
import discord
import asyncio

style.use("fivethirtyeight")

client = discord.Client()
TOKEN = '-----------------'  


async def get_input_of_type(func):
    while True:
        try:
            msg = await client.wait_for('message')
            return func(msg.content)
        except ValueError:
            continue

@client.event  # event decorator/wrapper
async def on_ready():
    global sentdex_guild
    print(f"We have logged in as {client.user}")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global sentdex_guild

    print(f"{message.channel}: {message.author}: {message.author.name}: {message.content}")


    if "hadescalc.logout()" == message.content.lower():
        await client.close()

    elif "hadescalc.planet()" == message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send("What is the first number?")
        firstnum = await get_input_of_type(int)
        firstnum = firstnum + 3
        await message.channel.send("What is the second number?")
        secondnum = await get_input_of_type(int)
        await message.channel.send(f"{firstnum} + {secondnum} = {firstnum+secondnum}")


    elif message.content.startswith('$planet_cap'):
        channel = message.channel
        try:
            class Planet:
                def __init__(self,level = 0,storage = 0,credit_per_hour = 0,cost = 0,types = 'desert',tier = 1):
                    self.level = level
                    self.storage = storage
                    self.credit_per_hour = credit_per_hour
                    self.cost = cost
                    self.types = types
                    self.tier = tier

                def __str__ (self):
                    return ('level: '+ self.level + ', storage cap: ' + self.storage + ', credits per hour: ' + self.credit_per_hour + ', cost to upgrade: ' + self.cost + ', Planet type: ' + self.types + ', planet tier: ' + self.tier)

                def set_planet_lvl(self,level):
                    self.level = level
                def get_planet_lvl(self):
                    return(self.level)
                def set_planet_cost(self,cost):
                    self.cost = cost
                def get_planet_cost(self):
                    return(self.cost)
                def set_planet_storage(self,storage):
                    self.storage = storage
                def get_planet_storage(self):
                    return(self.storage)
                def set_planet_credit_per_hour(self,credit_per_hour):
                    self.credit_per_hour = credit_per_hour
                def get_planet_credit_per_hour(self):
                    return(self.credit_per_hour)
                def get_planet_types(self):
                    return(self.types)
                def get_planet_tier(self):
                    return(self.tier)

            planet_list = {}


            await channel.send('how many planets do you have?')
            number = await get_input_of_type(int)
            await channel.send('for planet type, choose from desert,fire,water,terran,gas, and ice\n   ')
            await channel.send('for planet tier you can only do the folowing...\n \ndesert- 1,3,4\nfire- 1,3,4\nwater- 1,3,4\nterrran- 1,3,4\ngas- 2,4\nice- 4')
            for i in range(number):  
                await channel.send('level for the {} planet: '.format(i+1))
                levels = await get_input_of_type(str)
                print(levels)
                credit_cap = planet_cap(levels)
                print(credit_cap)

                await channel.send('planet type for the {} planet: '.format(i+1))
                planet_type = await get_input_of_type(str)

                await channel.send('planet tier for the {} planet: '.format(i+1))

                teirlvl = await get_input_of_type(str)
                credits_per_hour = credit_per_hour(planet_type,levels,teirlvl)

                cost = planet_cost(levels)

                planet_list[i] = (Planet(levels,credit_cap,credits_per_hour,cost,planet_type,teirlvl))

            orig_planet_lvl = []
            for i in planet_list:
                orig_planet_lvl.append(planet_list[i].get_planet_lvl())

            cost_list = []
            increase_in_cap = []
            increase_in_income = []
            decider = []
            temp_planets = planet_list.copy()

            current_storage = 0


            for i in temp_planets:
                storage = int(temp_planets[i].get_planet_storage())
                print(storage)
                current_storage += storage

            await channel.send(('Your starting storage is: ',current_storage))

            await channel.send('what is your credit cap goal: ')

            cap_goal = await get_input_of_type(int)

            max_levels = []

            for i in planet_list:
                max_levels.append(max_levels_planet(temp_planets[i].get_planet_types(),temp_planets[i].get_planet_tier()))

            while cap_goal >= current_storage:

                for i in temp_planets:

                    storage = temp_planets[i].get_planet_storage()
                    planet_lvl = temp_planets[i].get_planet_lvl()
                    credit_per_hours = temp_planets[i].get_planet_credit_per_hour()
                    planet_type = temp_planets[i].get_planet_types()
                    planet_tier = temp_planets[i].get_planet_tier()
                    new_lvl = str((int(planet_lvl) + 1))

                    if planet_lvl == max_levels[i]:
                        cost_list.append(temp_planets[i].get_planet_cost())
                        increase_in_cap.append('99999')
                        increase_in_income.append('99999')

                        decider.append('99')
                    else:
                        cost_list.append(temp_planets[i].get_planet_cost())



                        increase_cap = int(planet_cap(new_lvl))- int(storage)
                        if increase_cap == 0:
                            increase_cap = 1
                        increase_in_cap.append(increase_cap)


                        new_credits_per_hour = credit_per_hour(planet_type,new_lvl,planet_tier)
                        increase_in_incomees = (str(int(new_credits_per_hour)-int(credit_per_hours)))
                        if increase_in_incomees == 0:
                            increase_in_incomees = 1
                        increase_in_income.append(increase_in_incomees)


                        decider.append(str((int(cost_list[i])/int(increase_in_cap[i])/ int(increase_in_income[i]))))


                value = min(decider)
                first = ''
                for index,item in enumerate(decider):
                    if item == value:
                        if first == '':
                            await channel.send(('planet',(index +1), '--->', (int(temp_planets[index].get_planet_lvl())+1)))
                            temp_planets[index].set_planet_lvl(str(int(temp_planets[index].get_planet_lvl())+1))
                            temp_planets[index].set_planet_cost(str(planet_cost(str(temp_planets[index].get_planet_lvl()))))
                            temp_planets[index].set_planet_storage(str(planet_cost(str(temp_planets[index].get_planet_lvl()))))
                            temp_planets[index].set_planet_credit_per_hour(str(credit_per_hour(temp_planets[index].get_planet_types(),temp_planets[index].get_planet_lvl(),temp_planets[index].get_planet_tier())))
                            current_storage += int(temp_planets[index].get_planet_storage())
                            first = '1'
                cost_list = []
                increase_in_cap = []
                increase_in_income = []
                decider = []
                await channel.send('Your storage went up to: {} '.format(current_storage))
            await channel.send('Your final storage is: {}'.format(current_storage))

            for index,item in enumerate(planet_list):
                await channel.send(('{} planet whent from lvl'.format(index+1),orig_planet_lvl[index], 'to lvl',temp_planets[index].get_planet_lvl()))
        except (Exception, ValueError) as e:
            print(str(e))




client.run(TOKEN)
```

it waits for user input and if you enter something wrong it just breaks completely, i have tried to use try and except blocks but it wont recognize it either (I could be using it wrong).If anyone has a solution or something that would be great!

Comment: You really shouldn't make a class in the function...

Comment: also `planet_list` is a `dict` which is confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is too messy to understand what you want to do. I recommend you to clean up your code first, and rewrite the question. Followings are the problems your code has.

**1**

Use `check` instead of `get_input_of_type()`. Maybe `get_input_of_type()` works fine, but there already exists a function to check user message input. Your code seems to use this many times, so it is good to define a function for the shorter code.

```
def is_number(msg):
    return msg.content.isdigit()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "hadescalc.planet()" == message.content.lower():
        await client.send_message("What is the first number?")
        firstnumber = await client.wait_for_message(
            author=message.author,
            channel=message.channel,
            check=is_number)
        firstnumber += 3
        await client.send_message("What is the second number?")
        secondnumber = await client.wait_for_message(
            author=message.author,
            channel=message.channel,
            check=is_number)
        await client.send_message("{} + {} = {}".format(
            firstnumber, secondnumber, firstnumber+secondnumber))
```

**2**

Don't define `class` in a function. It is better to define `Planet` out of `on_message`. And instead of `set_***` and `get_***`, use `@property` and `@setter`.

```
class Planet:
    def __init__(self, level, ___):
        self._level = level
        # blah
        pass

    @property
    def level(self):
        return self._level

    @level.setter
    def level(self, new_level):
        self._level = new_level
```

**3**

You are casting `int` and `str` too many times, but this is not good. For example, `**_lvl` values are all `int` and no need to cast `str`. Remove all the unnecessary type casting. Also, i cannot understand what `decider` does, but it may not works as you want. `decider` is a `list` of `str`(all `int` in fact), so `min(decider)` finds alphabetical min value not the numeric min value. If you change `**_lvl` into `int` type, it will returns numeric min value as expected.